# 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' in python 3 IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, python-idle

[image]

Why is this a syntax error? And how do I fix it?

```
class Queue:

    #Queue is basicliy a List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []

    #add to the top of the list (the left side)
    def Enqueue(self, num):
        if isinstance(num, int):
            self.queue.append(num)

    #remove from the top of the list and return it to user
    def Dequeue(self):
        return self.queue.pop(0)

#this function gets inputs from user, and adds them to queue,
#until it gets 0.
def addToQueue(queue, num):
    num = input()
    while num != 0:
        queue.Enqueue(num)
        num = input()
```

Comment: Please paste the actual code, not a screenshot of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interactive mode (with the `>>>` prompt) only accepts one statement at a time.  You've entered two to be processed at once.

After you've entered the class definition, be sure to add an *extra* blank line so that the interactive prompt knows you're done.   Once you're prompted with a `>>>`, you'll know it is ready for the function definition.

The rest of your code looks fine.  Happy computing :-)

Comment: Tnx!
But if I have the entire code in one '*.py' file, it should be fine?